# GPS Coordinates to svg map

Tags: javascript, svg, gps

Is there a way to transform a GPS coordinates objects to an SVG map ?

I have Something like this object and I want to draw an svg map USING Javascript if it's possible (or any other language if it exists).

Thanks in advance for your help

```
{
 "type": "FeatureCollection",
 "features": [
        { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "area": 1.470000, "perimeter": 4.820000 }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -3.942000, 48.437000 ], [ -3.951000, 48.433998 ], [ -3.959000, 48.431999 ], [ -3.968000, 48.430000 ], [ -3.976000, 48.428001 ], [ -3.984000, 48.424999 ], [ -3.993000, 48.423000 ], [ -4.001000, 48.421001 ], [ -4.009000, 48.417999 ], [ -4.018000, 48.416000 ], [ -4.024000, 48.410999 ], [ -4.030000, 48.407001 ], [ -4.036000, 48.403000 ], [ -4.042000, 48.397999 ], [ -4.048000, 48.394001 ], [ -4.054000, 48.389000 ], [ -4.060000, 48.383999 ], [ -4.066000, 48.380001 ], [ -4.071000, 48.375000 ], [ -4.077000, 48.369999 ], [ -4.082000, 48.365002 ], [ -4.088000, 48.361000 ], [ -4.093000, 48.355999 ], [ -4.099000, 48.351002 ], [ -4.104000, 48.346001 ], [ -4.109000, 48.341000 ], [ -4.114000, 48.335999 ], [ -4.120000, 48.331001 ], [ -4.125000, 48.326000 ], [ -4.129000, 48.320999 ], [ -4.134000, 48.316002 ], [ -4.138000, 48.310001 ], [ -4.141000, 48.305000 ], [ -4.145000, 48.299000 ], [ -4.147000, 48.292999 ], [ -4.150000, 48.287998 ], [ -4.153000, 48.282001 ], [ -4.155000, 48.276001 ], [ -4.157000, 48.270000 ], [ -4.159000, 48.264000 ], [ -4.161000, 48.257999 ], [ -4.163000, 48.252998 ], [ -4.165000, 48.247002 ], [ -4.167000, 48.241001 ], [ -4.169000, 48.235001 ], [ -4.170000, 48.229000 ], [ -4.171000, 48.223000 ], [ -4.173000, 48.216999 ], [ -4.173000, 48.210999 ], [ -4.174000, 48.205002 ], [ -4.174000, 48.199001 ], [ -4.173000, 48.193001 ], [ -4.173000, 48.187000 ], [ -4.171000, 48.181000 ], [ -4.167000, 48.175999 ], [ -4.166000, 48.169998 ], [ -4.165000, 48.164001 ], [ -4.164000, 48.158001 ], [ -4.162000, 48.152000 ], [ -4.161000, 48.146000 ], [ -4.159000, 48.139999 ], [ -4.156000, 48.133999 ], [ -4.154000, 48.127998 ], [ -4.151000, 48.122002 ], [ -4.148000, 48.117001 ], [ -4.144000, 48.111000 ], [ -4.140000, 48.105999 ], [ -4.136000, 48.101002 ], [ -4.131000, 48.095001 ], [ -4.127000, 48.090000 ], [ -4.121000, 48.084999 ], [ -4.116000, 48.080002 ], [ -4.111000, 48.076000 ], [ -4.105000, 48.070999 ], [ -4.099000, 48.066002 ], [ -4.093000, 48.062000 ], [ -4.087000, 48.056999 ], [ -4.081000, 48.053001 ], [ -4.074000, 48.049000 ], [ -4.068000, 48.044998 ], [ -4.061000, 48.040001 ], [ -4.049000, 48.033001 ], [ -4.621000, 47.514000 ], [ -4.628000, 47.518002 ], [ -4.635000, 47.521999 ], [ -4.641000, 47.526001 ], [ -4.648000, 47.529999 ], [ -4.655000, 47.534000 ], [ -4.661000, 47.537998 ], [ -4.668000, 47.542000 ], [ -4.674000, 47.546001 ], [ -4.679000, 47.550999 ], [ -4.685000, 47.556000 ], [ -4.691000, 47.560001 ], [ -4.697000, 47.564999 ], [ -4.703000, 47.569000 ], [ -4.709000, 47.574001 ], [ -4.715000, 47.577999 ], [ -4.720000, 47.583000 ], [ -4.726000, 47.587002 ], [ -4.732000, 47.591999 ], [ -4.738000, 47.597000 ], [ -4.744000, 47.601002 ], [ -4.750000, 47.605999 ], [ -4.756000, 47.610001 ], [ -4.761000, 47.615002 ], [ -4.767000, 47.618999 ], [ -4.773000, 47.624001 ], [ -4.779000, 47.627998 ], [ -4.785000, 47.632999 ], [ -4.791000, 47.638000 ], [ -4.797000, 47.641998 ], [ -4.803000, 47.646999 ], [ -4.808000, 47.651001 ], [ -4.814000, 47.655998 ], [ -4.820000, 47.660000 ], [ -4.826000, 47.665001 ], [ -4.832000, 47.668999 ], [ -4.838000, 47.674000 ], [ -4.844000, 47.678001 ], [ -4.850000, 47.682999 ], [ -4.855000, 47.687000 ], [ -4.861000, 47.692001 ], [ -4.867000, 47.696999 ], [ -4.873000, 47.701000 ], [ -4.879000, 47.706001 ], [ -4.885000, 47.709999 ], [ -4.891000, 47.715000 ], [ -4.897000, 47.719002 ], [ -4.903000, 47.723999 ], [ -4.908000, 47.728001 ], [ -4.914000, 47.733002 ], [ -4.920000, 47.737000 ], [ -4.926000, 47.742001 ], [ -4.932000, 47.747002 ], [ -4.938000, 47.750999 ], [ -4.944000, 47.756001 ], [ -4.950000, 47.759998 ], [ -4.956000, 47.764999 ], [ -4.962000, 47.769001 ], [ -4.967000, 47.773998 ], [ -4.973000, 47.778000 ], [ -4.979000, 47.783001 ], [ -4.985000, 47.786999 ], [ -4.991000, 47.792000 ], [ -4.997000, 47.796001 ], [ -5.003000, 47.800999 ], [ -5.009000, 47.806000 ], [ -5.015000, 47.810001 ], [ -5.021000, 47.814999 ], [ -5.026000, 47.819000 ], [ -5.032000, 47.824001 ], [ -5.038000, 47.827999 ], [ -5.044000, 47.833000 ], [ -5.050000, 47.837002 ], [ -5.056000, 47.841999 ], [ -5.062000, 47.846001 ], [ -5.068000, 47.851002 ], [ -5.074000, 47.855000 ], [ -5.080000, 47.860001 ], [ -5.086000, 47.865002 ], [ -5.092000, 47.868999 ], [ -5.097000, 47.874001 ], [ -5.103000, 47.877998 ], [ -5.109000, 47.882999 ], [ -5.115000, 47.887001 ], [ -5.121000, 47.891998 ], [ -5.127000, 47.896000 ], [ -5.133000, 47.901001 ], [ -5.139000, 47.904999 ], [ -5.145000, 47.910000 ], [ -5.151000, 47.914001 ], [ -5.157000, 47.918999 ], [ -5.163000, 47.924000 ], [ -5.168000, 47.928001 ], [ -5.174000, 47.932999 ], [ -5.180000, 47.937000 ], [ -5.186000, 47.942001 ], [ -5.192000, 47.945999 ], [ -5.198000, 47.951000 ], [ -5.204000, 47.955002 ], [ -5.210000, 47.959999 ], [ -5.216000, 47.964001 ], [ -5.222000, 47.969002 ], [ -5.228000, 47.973000 ], [ -5.233000, 47.978001 ], [ -5.238000, 47.983002 ], [ -5.243000, 47.987999 ], [ -5.247000, 47.993999 ], [ -5.251000, 47.999001 ], [ -5.255000, 48.005001 ], [ -5.259000, 48.009998 ], [ -5.264000, 48.014999 ], [ -5.269000, 48.020000 ], [ -5.274000, 48.025002 ], [ -5.277000, 48.030998 ], [ -5.280000, 48.035999 ], [ -5.283000, 48.042000 ], [ -5.285000, 48.048000 ], [ -5.286000, 48.054001 ], [ -5.287000, 48.060001 ], [ -5.287000, 48.066002 ], [ -5.287000, 48.071999 ], [ -5.288000, 48.077999 ], [ -5.288000, 48.084000 ], [ -5.289000, 48.090000 ], [ -5.289000, 48.096001 ], [ -5.290000, 48.102001 ], [ -5.290000, 48.108002 ], [ -5.291000, 48.113998 ], [ -5.291000, 48.119999 ], [ -5.292000, 48.125999 ], [ -5.292000, 48.132000 ], [ -5.292000, 48.138000 ], [ -5.293000, 48.144001 ], [ -5.293000, 48.150002 ], [ -5.294000, 48.155998 ], [ -5.294000, 48.161999 ], [ -5.295000, 48.167999 ], [ -5.295000, 48.174000 ], [ -5.296000, 48.181000 ], [ -5.296000, 48.187000 ], [ -5.296000, 48.193001 ], [ -5.297000, 48.199001 ], [ -5.297000, 48.205002 ], [ -5.298000, 48.210999 ], [ -5.298000, 48.216999 ], [ -5.299000, 48.223000 ], [ -5.299000, 48.229000 ], [ -5.299000, 48.235001 ], [ -5.300000, 48.241001 ], [ -5.300000, 48.247002 ], [ -5.301000, 48.252998 ], [ -5.301000, 48.258999 ], [ -5.302000, 48.264999 ], [ -5.302000, 48.271000 ], [ -5.302000, 48.277000 ], [ -5.303000, 48.283001 ], [ -5.303000, 48.289001 ], [ -5.304000, 48.294998 ], [ -5.304000, 48.300999 ], [ -5.305000, 48.306999 ], [ -5.305000, 48.313000 ], [ -5.305000, 48.319000 ], [ -5.306000, 48.325001 ], [ -5.306000, 48.331001 ], [ -5.306000, 48.337002 ], [ -5.306000, 48.342999 ], [ -5.305000, 48.348999 ], [ -5.305000, 48.355000 ], [ -5.304000, 48.361000 ], [ -5.304000, 48.367001 ], [ -5.304000, 48.373001 ], [ -5.304000, 48.379002 ], [ -5.304000, 48.384998 ], [ -5.305000, 48.391998 ], [ -5.305000, 48.397999 ], [ -5.305000, 48.403999 ], [ -5.305000, 48.410000 ], [ -5.306000, 48.416000 ], [ -5.306000, 48.422001 ], [ -5.306000, 48.428001 ], [ -5.307000, 48.433998 ], [ -5.307000, 48.439999 ], [ -5.307000, 48.445999 ], [ -5.308000, 48.452000 ], [ -5.308000, 48.458000 ], [ -5.308000, 48.464001 ], [ -5.309000, 48.470001 ], [ -5.309000, 48.476002 ], [ -5.309000, 48.481998 ], [ -5.310000, 48.487999 ], [ -5.310000, 48.493999 ], [ -5.310000, 48.500000 ], [ -5.310000, 48.506001 ], [ -5.310000, 48.512001 ], [ -5.310000, 48.518002 ], [ -5.309000, 48.523998 ], [ -5.309000, 48.529999 ], [ -5.309000, 48.535999 ], [ -5.308000, 48.542000 ], [ -5.308000, 48.548000 ], [ -5.307000, 48.554001 ], [ -5.306000, 48.560001 ], [ -5.305000, 48.566002 ], [ -5.303000, 48.571999 ], [ -5.302000, 48.577999 ], [ -5.300000, 48.584000 ], [ -5.299000, 48.590000 ], [ -5.297000, 48.596001 ], [ -5.294000, 48.602001 ], [ -5.292000, 48.608002 ], [ -5.289000, 48.612999 ], [ -5.286000, 48.618999 ], [ -5.283000, 48.625000 ], [ -5.279000, 48.630001 ], [ -5.276000, 48.636002 ], [ -5.271000, 48.640999 ], [ -5.267000, 48.646000 ], [ -5.263000, 48.652000 ], [ -5.258000, 48.657001 ], [ -5.253000, 48.661999 ], [ -5.248000, 48.667000 ], [ -5.243000, 48.672001 ], [ -5.238000, 48.676998 ], [ -5.232000, 48.681999 ], [ -5.227000, 48.687000 ], [ -5.221000, 48.691002 ], [ -5.216000, 48.695999 ], [ -5.210000, 48.701000 ], [ -5.204000, 48.705002 ], [ -5.198000, 48.709999 ], [ -5.192000, 48.714001 ], [ -5.186000, 48.719002 ], [ -5.180000, 48.723000 ], [ -5.173000, 48.728001 ], [ -5.167000, 48.731998 ], [ -5.160000, 48.736000 ], [ -5.154000, 48.740002 ], [ -5.147000, 48.744999 ], [ -5.141000, 48.749001 ], [ -5.134000, 48.752998 ], [ -5.127000, 48.757000 ], [ -5.121000, 48.761002 ], [ -5.114000, 48.764999 ], [ -5.107000, 48.769001 ], [ -5.100000, 48.772999 ], [ -5.093000, 48.777000 ], [ -5.086000, 48.780998 ], [ -5.079000, 48.785000 ], [ -5.072000, 48.789001 ], [ -5.065000, 48.792000 ], [ -5.058000, 48.796001 ], [ -5.051000, 48.799999 ], [ -5.044000, 48.804001 ], [ -5.037000, 48.807999 ], [ -5.030000, 48.811001 ], [ -5.023000, 48.814999 ], [ -5.015000, 48.819000 ], [ -5.008000, 48.823002 ], [ -5.001000, 48.826000 ], [ -4.994000, 48.830002 ], [ -4.987000, 48.834000 ], [ -4.980000, 48.838001 ], [ -4.972000, 48.841000 ], [ -4.965000, 48.845001 ], [ -4.958000, 48.848999 ], [ -4.951000, 48.853001 ], [ -4.944000, 48.855999 ], [ -4.937000, 48.860001 ], [ -4.930000, 48.863998 ], [ -4.922000, 48.868000 ], [ -4.915000, 48.872002 ], [ -4.908000, 48.875000 ], [ -4.901000, 48.879002 ], [ -4.894000, 48.882999 ], [ -4.887000, 48.887001 ], [ -4.880000, 48.890999 ], [ -4.873000, 48.895000 ], [ -4.866000, 48.898998 ], [ -4.860000, 48.903000 ], [ -4.853000, 48.907001 ], [ -4.846000, 48.910999 ], [ -4.839000, 48.915001 ], [ -4.832000, 48.918999 ], [ -4.826000, 48.923000 ], [ -4.818000, 48.926998 ], [ -4.811000, 48.930000 ], [ -4.804000, 48.933998 ], [ -4.797000, 48.938000 ], [ -4.790000, 48.942001 ], [ -4.783000, 48.945999 ], [ -4.776000, 48.950001 ], [ -4.769000, 48.953999 ], [ -4.763000, 48.958000 ], [ -4.757000, 48.963001 ], [ -4.750000, 48.966999 ], [ -4.742000, 48.969002 ], [ -4.733000, 48.971001 ], [ -4.725000, 48.973999 ], [ -4.717000, 48.976002 ], [ -4.708000, 48.979000 ], [ -4.700000, 48.981998 ], [ -4.692000, 48.985001 ], [ -4.684000, 48.987000 ], [ -4.676000, 48.990002 ], [ -4.668000, 48.993000 ], [ -4.659000, 48.994999 ], [ -4.650000, 48.997002 ], [ -4.642000, 48.999001 ], [ -4.633000, 49.000000 ], [ -4.624000, 49.001999 ], [ -4.615000, 49.004002 ], [ -4.606000, 49.006001 ], [ -4.598000, 49.007000 ], [ -4.589000, 49.008999 ], [ -4.580000, 49.011002 ], [ -4.571000, 49.013000 ], [ -4.563000, 49.014999 ], [ -4.554000, 49.015999 ], [ -4.545000, 49.018002 ], [ -4.536000, 49.020000 ], [ -4.528000, 49.021999 ], [ -4.519000, 49.023998 ], [ -4.510000, 49.025002 ], [ -4.501000, 49.027000 ], [ -4.493000, 49.028999 ], [ -4.484000, 49.030998 ], [ -4.475000, 49.033001 ], [ -4.466000, 49.034000 ], [ -4.458000, 49.035999 ], [ -4.449000, 49.037998 ], [ -4.440000, 49.040001 ], [ -4.431000, 49.041000 ], [ -4.423000, 49.042999 ], [ -4.414000, 49.044998 ], [ -4.405000, 49.047001 ], [ -4.396000, 49.049000 ], [ -4.388000, 49.049999 ], [ -4.379000, 49.051998 ], [ -4.370000, 49.054001 ], [ -4.361000, 49.056000 ], [ -4.353000, 49.057999 ], [ -4.344000, 49.058998 ], [ -4.335000, 49.061001 ], [ -4.326000, 49.063000 ], [ -4.317000, 49.064999 ], [ -4.309000, 49.066002 ], [ -4.300000, 49.068001 ], [ -4.291000, 49.070000 ], [ -4.282000, 49.070999 ], [ -4.273000, 49.073002 ], [ -4.265000, 49.075001 ], [ -4.256000, 49.077000 ], [ -4.247000, 49.077999 ], [ -4.238000, 49.080002 ], [ -4.229000, 49.082001 ], [ -4.221000, 49.083000 ], [ -4.212000, 49.084999 ], [ -4.203000, 49.087002 ], [ -4.194000, 49.088001 ], [ -4.185000, 49.090000 ], [ -4.176000, 49.091000 ], [ -4.167000, 49.092999 ], [ -4.159000, 49.095001 ], [ -4.150000, 49.096001 ], [ -4.141000, 49.098000 ], [ -4.132000, 49.098999 ], [ -4.123000, 49.101002 ], [ -4.114000, 49.102001 ], [ -4.105000, 49.104000 ], [ -4.096000, 49.105000 ], [ -4.088000, 49.106998 ], [ -4.079000, 49.108002 ], [ -4.063093, 49.110609 ], [ -3.942000, 48.437000 ] ] ] } }
        ,
        { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "area": 0.870000, "perimeter": 4.320000 }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -4.049000, 48.033001 ], [ -4.061000, 48.040001 ], [ -4.068000, 48.044998 ], [ -4.074000, 48.049000 ], [ -4.081000, 48.053001 ], [ -4.087000, 48.056999 ], [ -4.093000, 48.062000 ], [ -4.099000, 48.066002 ], [ -4.105000, 48.070999 ], [ -4.111000, 48.076000 ], [ -4.116000, 48.080002 ], [ -4.121000, 48.084999 ], [ -4.127000, 48.090000 ], [ -4.131000, 48.095001 ], [ -4.136000, 48.101002 ], [ -4.140000, 48.105999 ], [ -4.144000, 48.111000 ], [ -4.148000, 48.117001 ], [ -4.151000, 48.122002 ], [ -4.154000, 48.127998 ], [ -4.156000, 48.133999 ], [ -4.159000, 48.139999 ], [ -4.161000, 48.146000 ], [ -4.162000, 48.152000 ], [ -4.164000, 48.158001 ], [ -4.165000, 48.164001 ], [ -4.166000, 48.169998 ], [ -4.167000, 48.175999 ], [ -4.171000, 48.181000 ], [ -4.173000, 48.187000 ], [ -4.173000, 48.193001 ], [ -4.174000, 48.199001 ], [ -4.174000, 48.205002 ], [ -4.173000, 48.210999 ], [ -4.173000, 48.216999 ], [ -4.171000, 48.223000 ], [ -4.170000, 48.229000 ], [ -4.169000, 48.235001 ], [ -4.167000, 48.241001 ], [ -4.165000, 48.247002 ], [ -4.163000, 48.252998 ], [ -4.161000, 48.257999 ], [ -4.159000, 48.264000 ], [ -4.157000, 48.270000 ], [ -4.155000, 48.276001 ], [ -4.153000, 48.282001 ], [ -4.150000, 48.287998 ], [ -4.147000, 48.292999 ], [ -4.145000, 48.299000 ], [ -4.141000, 48.305000 ], [ -4.138000, 48.310001 ], [ -4.134000, 48.316002 ], [ -4.129000, 48.320999 ], [ -4.125000, 48.326000 ], [ -4.120000, 48.331001 ], [ -4.114000, 48.335999 ], [ -4.109000, 48.341000 ], [ -4.104000, 48.346001 ], [ -4.099000, 48.351002 ], [ -4.093000, 48.355999 ], [ -4.088000, 48.361000 ], [ -4.082000, 48.365002 ], [ -4.077000, 48.369999 ], [ -4.071000, 48.375000 ], [ -4.066000, 48.380001 ], [ -4.060000, 48.383999 ], [ -4.054000, 48.389000 ], [ -4.048000, 48.394001 ], [ -4.042000, 48.397999 ], [ -4.036000, 48.403000 ], [ -4.030000, 48.407001 ], [ -4.024000, 48.410999 ], [ -4.018000, 48.416000 ], [ -4.009000, 48.417999 ], [ -4.001000, 48.421001 ], [ -3.993000, 48.423000 ], [ -3.984000, 48.424999 ], [ -3.976000, 48.428001 ], [ -3.968000, 48.430000 ], [ -3.959000, 48.431999 ], [ -3.951000, 48.433998 ], [ -3.942000, 48.437000 ], [ -3.934000, 48.438999 ], [ -3.926000, 48.441002 ], [ -3.917000, 48.444000 ], [ -3.909000, 48.445999 ], [ -3.901000, 48.449001 ], [ -3.893000, 48.452000 ], [ -3.884000, 48.453999 ], [ -3.876000, 48.456001 ], [ -3.868000, 48.459000 ], [ -3.859000, 48.460999 ], [ -3.851000, 48.463001 ], [ -3.843000, 48.465000 ], [ -3.834000, 48.466999 ], [ -3.825000, 48.469002 ], [ -3.816000, 48.471001 ], [ -3.808000, 48.472000 ], [ -3.799000, 48.473999 ], [ -3.790000, 48.474998 ], [ -3.781000, 48.476002 ], [ -3.772000, 48.478001 ], [ -3.764000, 48.479000 ], [ -3.755000, 48.480999 ], [ -3.746000, 48.481998 ], [ -3.737000, 48.483002 ], [ -3.728000, 48.484001 ], [ -3.719000, 48.486000 ], [ -3.710000, 48.487000 ], [ -3.701000, 48.487999 ], [ -3.692000, 48.488998 ], [ -3.684000, 48.490002 ], [ -3.675000, 48.491001 ], [ -3.666000, 48.492001 ], [ -3.657000, 48.493000 ], [ -3.648000, 48.493999 ], [ -3.639000, 48.494999 ], [ -3.630000, 48.495998 ], [ -3.621000, 48.497002 ], [ -3.612000, 48.497002 ], [ -3.603000, 48.498001 ], [ -3.594000, 48.499001 ], [ -3.585000, 48.500000 ], [ -3.576000, 48.500000 ], [ -3.567000, 48.500999 ], [ -3.558000, 48.500999 ], [ -3.549000, 48.501999 ], [ -3.540000, 48.501999 ], [ -3.530000, 48.501999 ], [ -3.521000, 48.502998 ], [ -3.512000, 48.502998 ], [ -3.503000, 48.502998 ], [ -3.494000, 48.502998 ], [ -3.485000, 48.502998 ], [ -3.476000, 48.502998 ], [ -3.467000, 48.502998 ], [ -3.458000, 48.502998 ], [ -3.449000, 48.502998 ], [ -3.440000, 48.502998 ], [ -3.431000, 48.502998 ], [ -3.422000, 48.502998 ], [ -3.412000, 48.502998 ], [ -3.403000, 48.502998 ], [ -3.394000, 48.502998 ], [ -3.385000, 48.502998 ], [ -3.376000, 48.502998 ], [ -3.367000, 48.502998 ], [ -3.358000, 48.502998 ], [ -3.349000, 48.502998 ], [ -3.340000, 48.502998 ], [ -3.331000, 48.504002 ], [ -3.322000, 48.505001 ], [ -3.313000, 48.505001 ], [ -3.304000, 48.506001 ], [ -3.295000, 48.507000 ], [ -3.286000, 48.507999 ], [ -3.277000, 48.507999 ], [ -3.268000, 48.508999 ], [ -3.259000, 48.509998 ], [ -3.250000, 48.511002 ], [ -3.241000, 48.512001 ], [ -3.232000, 48.512001 ], [ -3.223000, 48.513000 ], [ -3.214000, 48.513000 ], [ -3.205000, 48.513000 ], [ -3.195000, 48.513000 ], [ -3.186000, 48.513000 ], [ -3.177000, 48.513000 ], [ -3.168000, 48.512001 ], [ -3.159000, 48.512001 ], [ -3.150000, 48.509998 ], [ -3.142000, 48.508999 ], [ -3.133000, 48.507000 ], [ -3.125000, 48.505001 ], [ -3.116000, 48.501999 ], [ -3.108000, 48.500000 ], [ -3.100000, 48.497002 ], [ -3.092000, 48.493999 ], [ -3.084000, 48.492001 ], [ -3.076000, 48.488998 ], [ -3.068000, 48.486000 ], [ -3.060000, 48.483002 ], [ -3.052000, 48.479000 ], [ -3.045000, 48.476002 ], [ -3.037000, 48.473000 ], [ -3.029000, 48.470001 ], [ -3.022000, 48.466000 ], [ -3.015000, 48.463001 ], [ -3.007000, 48.459000 ], [ -3.000000, 48.456001 ], [ -2.992000, 48.452000 ], [ -2.985000, 48.449001 ], [ -2.978000, 48.445000 ], [ -2.971000, 48.441002 ], [ -2.964000, 48.438000 ], [ -2.956000, 48.433998 ], [ -2.949000, 48.430000 ], [ -2.942000, 48.425999 ], [ -2.935000, 48.423000 ], [ -2.928000, 48.418999 ], [ -2.921000, 48.415001 ], [ -2.914000, 48.410999 ], [ -2.907000, 48.408001 ], [ -2.900000, 48.403999 ], [ -2.893000, 48.400002 ], [ -2.885000, 48.396000 ], [ -2.878000, 48.393002 ], [ -2.871000, 48.389000 ], [ -2.864000, 48.384998 ], [ -2.857000, 48.381001 ], [ -2.850000, 48.377998 ], [ -2.843000, 48.374001 ], [ -2.835000, 48.369999 ], [ -2.828000, 48.367001 ], [ -2.821000, 48.362999 ], [ -2.813000, 48.360001 ], [ -2.806000, 48.355999 ], [ -2.799000, 48.353001 ], [ -2.791000, 48.349998 ], [ -2.783000, 48.346001 ], [ -2.776000, 48.342999 ], [ -2.768000, 48.340000 ], [ -2.760000, 48.337002 ], [ -2.752000, 48.334000 ], [ -2.744000, 48.332001 ], [ -2.735000, 48.331001 ], [ -2.726000, 48.330002 ], [ -2.717000, 48.328999 ], [ -2.708000, 48.327999 ], [ -2.699000, 48.327000 ], [ -2.690000, 48.326000 ], [ -2.681000, 48.324001 ], [ -2.673000, 48.323002 ], [ -2.664000, 48.320999 ], [ -2.655000, 48.320000 ], [ -2.646000, 48.318001 ], [ -2.638000, 48.317001 ], [ -2.629000, 48.314999 ], [ -2.620000, 48.313999 ], [ -2.611000, 48.312000 ], [ -2.603000, 48.311001 ], [ -2.594000, 48.308998 ], [ -2.585000, 48.307999 ], [ -2.576000, 48.306000 ], [ -2.567000, 48.305000 ], [ -2.559000, 48.303001 ], [ -2.550000, 48.301998 ], [ -2.541000, 48.299999 ], [ -2.532000, 48.299000 ], [ -2.524000, 48.297001 ], [ -2.515000, 48.296001 ], [ -2.506000, 48.293999 ], [ -2.497000, 48.292999 ], [ -2.489000, 48.291000 ], [ -2.480000, 48.290001 ], [ -2.471000, 48.287998 ], [ -2.462000, 48.286999 ], [ -2.454000, 48.285000 ], [ -2.445000, 48.284000 ], [ -2.436000, 48.282001 ], [ -2.427000, 48.280998 ], [ -2.419000, 48.278999 ], [ -2.410000, 48.277000 ], [ -2.401000, 48.276001 ], [ -2.392000, 48.273998 ], [ -2.384000, 48.272999 ], [ -2.375000, 48.271000 ], [ -2.366000, 48.270000 ], [ -2.358000, 48.268002 ], [ -2.349000, 48.266998 ], [ -2.340000, 48.264999 ], [ -2.331000, 48.263000 ], [ -2.325000, 48.262001 ], [ -2.332000, 48.245998 ], [ -2.335000, 48.240002 ], [ -2.337000, 48.234001 ], [ -2.340000, 48.228001 ], [ -2.342000, 48.222000 ], [ -2.345000, 48.216999 ], [ -2.347000, 48.210999 ], [ -2.350000, 48.205002 ], [ -2.352000, 48.199001 ], [ -2.355000, 48.193001 ], [ -2.357000, 48.188000 ], [ -2.360000, 48.181999 ], [ -2.362000, 48.175999 ], [ -2.365000, 48.169998 ], [ -2.368000, 48.165001 ], [ -2.370000, 48.159000 ], [ -2.373000, 48.153000 ], [ -2.376000, 48.146999 ], [ -2.378000, 48.141998 ], [ -2.381000, 48.136002 ], [ -2.384000, 48.130001 ], [ -2.387000, 48.124001 ], [ -2.390000, 48.118999 ], [ -2.392000, 48.112999 ], [ -2.395000, 48.106998 ], [ -2.398000, 48.101002 ], [ -2.401000, 48.096001 ], [ -2.404000, 48.090000 ], [ -2.407000, 48.084000 ], [ -2.409000, 48.077999 ], [ -2.412000, 48.073002 ], [ -2.415000, 48.067001 ], [ -2.418000, 48.061001 ], [ -2.421000, 48.056000 ], [ -2.424000, 48.049999 ], [ -2.427000, 48.043999 ], [ -2.430000, 48.039001 ], [ -2.433000, 48.033001 ], [ -2.436000, 48.027000 ], [ -2.439000, 48.021000 ], [ -2.442000, 48.015999 ], [ -2.445000, 48.009998 ], [ -2.448000, 48.004002 ], [ -2.451000, 47.999001 ], [ -2.454000, 47.993000 ], [ -2.457000, 47.987000 ], [ -2.460000, 47.981998 ], [ -2.463000, 47.976002 ], [ -2.466000, 47.970001 ], [ -2.469000, 47.965000 ], [ -2.472000, 47.959000 ], [ -2.475000, 47.952999 ], [ -2.478000, 47.946999 ], [ -2.481000, 47.942001 ], [ -2.484000, 47.936001 ], [ -2.487000, 47.930000 ], [ -2.490000, 47.924999 ], [ -2.493000, 47.918999 ], [ -2.496000, 47.912998 ], [ -2.499000, 47.908001 ], [ -2.502000, 47.902000 ], [ -2.505000, 47.896000 ], [ -2.508000, 47.890999 ], [ -2.511000, 47.884998 ], [ -2.514000, 47.879002 ], [ -2.517000, 47.874001 ], [ -2.520000, 47.868000 ], [ -2.523000, 47.862000 ], [ -2.526000, 47.856998 ], [ -2.529000, 47.851002 ], [ -2.532000, 47.845001 ], [ -2.535000, 47.840000 ], [ -2.538000, 47.834000 ], [ -2.541000, 47.827999 ], [ -2.544000, 47.821999 ], [ -2.547000, 47.817001 ], [ -2.550000, 47.811001 ], [ -2.553000, 47.805000 ], [ -2.556000, 47.799999 ], [ -2.559000, 47.793999 ], [ -2.562000, 47.787998 ], [ -2.565000, 47.783001 ], [ -2.568000, 47.777000 ], [ -2.570000, 47.771000 ], [ -2.573000, 47.764999 ], [ -2.586000, 47.771000 ], [ -2.594000, 47.773998 ], [ -2.601000, 47.777000 ], [ -2.609000, 47.779999 ], [ -2.617000, 47.783001 ], [ -2.624000, 47.785999 ], [ -2.632000, 47.789001 ], [ -2.640000, 47.792999 ], [ -2.647000, 47.796001 ], [ -2.655000, 47.799000 ], [ -2.663000, 47.801998 ], [ -2.670000, 47.805000 ], [ -2.678000, 47.807999 ], [ -2.686000, 47.811001 ], [ -2.694000, 47.813999 ], [ -2.701000, 47.817001 ], [ -2.709000, 47.820000 ], [ -2.717000, 47.823002 ], [ -2.725000, 47.826000 ], [ -2.732000, 47.828999 ], [ -2.740000, 47.832001 ], [ -2.748000, 47.834999 ], [ -2.755000, 47.838001 ], [ -2.764000, 47.838001 ], [ -2.772000, 47.840000 ], [ -2.781000, 47.842999 ], [ -2.789000, 47.845001 ], [ -2.797000, 47.847000 ], [ -2.805000, 47.849998 ], [ -2.814000, 47.852001 ], [ -2.822000, 47.854000 ], [ -2.831000, 47.855999 ], [ -2.839000, 47.858002 ], [ -2.848000, 47.860001 ], [ -2.856000, 47.862000 ], [ -2.864000, 47.863998 ], [ -2.873000, 47.867001 ], [ -2.881000, 47.868999 ], [ -2.889000, 47.870998 ], [ -2.898000, 47.873001 ], [ -2.906000, 47.875000 ], [ -2.915000, 47.875999 ], [ -2.924000, 47.877998 ], [ -2.932000, 47.879002 ], [ -2.941000, 47.881001 ], [ -2.950000, 47.882000 ], [ -2.958000, 47.883999 ], [ -2.967000, 47.886002 ], [ -2.975000, 47.888000 ], [ -2.984000, 47.889999 ], [ -2.992000, 47.891998 ], [ -3.001000, 47.893002 ], [ -3.010000, 47.895000 ], [ -3.019000, 47.896000 ], [ -3.027000, 47.896999 ], [ -3.036000, 47.897999 ], [ -3.045000, 47.898998 ], [ -3.054000, 47.900002 ], [ -3.063000, 47.901001 ], [ -3.072000, 47.902000 ], [ -3.081000, 47.903000 ], [ -3.089000, 47.903999 ], [ -3.098000, 47.905998 ], [ -3.107000, 47.907001 ], [ -3.115000, 47.909000 ], [ -3.124000, 47.910000 ], [ -3.133000, 47.910999 ], [ -3.142000, 47.912998 ], [ -3.150000, 47.914001 ], [ -3.159000, 47.915001 ], [ -3.168000, 47.917000 ], [ -3.177000, 47.917999 ], [ -3.185000, 47.918999 ], [ -3.194000, 47.921001 ], [ -3.203000, 47.922001 ], [ -3.212000, 47.923000 ], [ -3.220000, 47.924999 ], [ -3.229000, 47.925999 ], [ -3.238000, 47.926998 ], [ -3.247000, 47.929001 ], [ -3.255000, 47.930000 ], [ -3.264000, 47.931000 ], [ -3.273000, 47.932999 ], [ -3.282000, 47.933998 ], [ -3.290000, 47.935001 ], [ -3.299000, 47.937000 ], [ -3.308000, 47.938000 ], [ -3.317000, 47.938999 ], [ -3.326000, 47.941002 ], [ -3.334000, 47.942001 ], [ -3.343000, 47.943001 ], [ -3.352000, 47.944000 ], [ -3.361000, 47.945999 ], [ -3.369000, 47.946999 ], [ -3.378000, 47.948002 ], [ -3.387000, 47.949001 ], [ -3.396000, 47.951000 ], [ -3.405000, 47.952000 ], [ -3.413000, 47.952999 ], [ -3.422000, 47.953999 ], [ -3.431000, 47.956001 ], [ -3.440000, 47.957001 ], [ -3.449000, 47.958000 ], [ -3.457000, 47.959000 ], [ -3.466000, 47.959999 ], [ -3.475000, 47.960999 ], [ -3.484000, 47.963001 ], [ -3.493000, 47.964001 ], [ -3.502000, 47.965000 ], [ -3.510000, 47.966000 ], [ -3.519000, 47.966999 ], [ -3.528000, 47.967999 ], [ -3.537000, 47.969002 ], [ -3.546000, 47.970001 ], [ -3.555000, 47.971001 ], [ -3.563000, 47.972000 ], [ -3.572000, 47.973000 ], [ -3.581000, 47.973999 ], [ -3.590000, 47.974998 ], [ -3.599000, 47.976002 ], [ -3.608000, 47.977001 ], [ -3.617000, 47.978001 ], [ -3.625000, 47.979000 ], [ -3.634000, 47.980000 ], [ -3.643000, 47.980999 ], [ -3.652000, 47.981998 ], [ -3.661000, 47.983002 ], [ -3.670000, 47.984001 ], [ -3.679000, 47.985001 ], [ -3.688000, 47.985001 ], [ -3.697000, 47.986000 ], [ -3.706000, 47.987000 ], [ -3.714000, 47.987999 ], [ -3.723000, 47.988998 ], [ -3.732000, 47.990002 ], [ -3.741000, 47.990002 ], [ -3.750000, 47.991001 ], [ -3.759000, 47.992001 ], [ -3.768000, 47.993000 ], [ -3.777000, 47.993000 ], [ -3.786000, 47.993999 ], [ -3.795000, 47.994999 ], [ -3.804000, 47.995998 ], [ -3.813000, 47.995998 ], [ -3.821000, 47.997002 ], [ -3.830000, 47.998001 ], [ -3.839000, 47.998001 ], [ -3.848000, 47.999001 ], [ -3.857000, 48.000000 ], [ -3.866000, 48.000000 ], [ -3.875000, 48.000999 ], [ -3.884000, 48.001999 ], [ -3.893000, 48.001999 ], [ -3.902000, 48.002998 ], [ -3.911000, 48.004002 ], [ -3.920000, 48.004002 ], [ -3.929000, 48.005001 ], [ -3.938000, 48.006001 ], [ -3.946000, 48.007000 ], [ -3.955000, 48.007999 ], [ -3.964000, 48.007000 ], [ -3.972000, 48.004002 ], [ -3.981000, 48.004002 ], [ -3.989000, 48.007000 ], [ -3.996000, 48.009998 ], [ -4.004000, 48.013000 ], [ -4.012000, 48.015999 ], [ -4.020000, 48.019001 ], [ -4.027000, 48.022999 ], [ -4.035000, 48.026001 ], [ -4.042000, 48.028999 ], [ -4.049000, 48.033001 ] ] ] } }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: Take a look at D3.js